# How do I refresh an input element after submitting a form in Next.js with Server Actions?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, app-router, server-action

I have a contact form. I want to refresh my input elements after submitting that form. I'm using the latest version of Next.js with Server Actions. I've searched this problem on Next.js documentation, but couldn't find any solution to the problem.

My server action code

```
"use server"

export const handleContactForm = async (previousState, formData) => {
    const { fName, lName, email, message } = Object.fromEntries(formData);
    try {
        await connectToDB();
        const newContactUser = new ContactUser({
            fName,
            lName,
            email,
            message
        })
        await newContactUser.save();
        console.log("Contact user data saved");
        revalidatePath("/contact")

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return {error: "Something went wrong due to some technical issues!"}
    }
}
```

my contact form

```
const Contact = () => {
    const [state, formAction] = useFormState(handleContactForm, undefined)
    const { pending, data } = useFormStatus();
    const { showAlert } = useContext(AlertContext);
  
    return (
        <ComponentLayout className='md:pb-16 pb-8'>
            <PageHeader
                pageHeading='Get in touch'
                pageLabel='Contact us'
            />
            <FormLayout
                formDesc='contact'
                className='dark:bg-black dark:bg-opacity-30 py-8 mt-14 card-border card-light-shadow card-dark-shadow bg-emerald-200 bg-opacity-10 px-8'
            >
                <form
                    action={formAction}
                    className="space-y-5"
                >
                    <h1 className='blue_gradient orange_gradient md:text-xl text-lg tracking-wide font-bold uppercase text-center mb-8'>Contact form</h1>
                    <div className="flex flex-col items-center gap-y-5 gap-x-6 [&>*]:w-full sm:flex-row">
                        <div>
                            <InputLabel
                                labelText='First name'
                            />
                            <InputTag
                                type='text'
                                name='fName'
                                placeHolder='Ex- John'
                                className='dark:focus:border-indigo-600 focus:border-green-600'
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <InputLabel
                                labelText='Last name'
                            />
                            <InputTag
                                type='text'
                                name='lName'
                                placeHolder='Ex- Smith'
                                className='dark:focus:border-indigo-600 focus:border-green-600'
                            />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <InputLabel
                            labelText='Email'
                        />
                        <InputTag
                            type='email'
                            name='email'
                            placeHolder='Ex- example@email.com'
                            className='dark:focus:border-indigo-600 focus:border-green-600'
                        />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <InputLabel
                            labelText='Message'
                        />
                        <textarea
                            required
                            spellCheck="false"
                            name='message'
                            placeholder='Ex- I have an importent message for you...'
                            className="w-full mt-2 h-32 px-3 py-2 resize-none appearance-none outline-none border mb-4 dark:focus:border-indigo-600 shadow-sm rounded-lg border-gray-400 border-opacity-40 dark:border-opacity-20 tracking-wide dark:focus:bg-transparent focus:border-green-600 focus:bg-gray-100 bg-transparent dark:bg-transparent dark:text-yellow-400 text-neutral-600 dark:placeholder:text-neutral-500 placeholder:text-neutral-400 font-inter"></textarea>
                    </div>
                    <div className='grid place-items-center'>
                        <BigButton
                            disabled={pending}
                            buttonText={pending ? 'Submitting...' : 'Submit'}
                            darkButtonClasses='text-button-primary blue-button'
                            lightButtonClasses='text-button-primary green-button'
                        />
                    </div>
                </form>
            </FormLayout>
        </ComponentLayout>
    )
}
```

Please suggest me a better solution.

Comment: After submission, please refetch and reSet the state if you want recent data from server. Otherwise, set default value to the state